# Overstayed in Turkey

Tags: visas, turkey, overstaying

I have overstayed in Turkey for 8 months now. My travel agent has gotten a Canadian visa for me. Do I need to return first to my home country and then travel to Canada. Or is it possible for me to exit Turkey, where I am, then go on to Canada?

Comment: Where was your Canadian visa issued? Turkey or in your home country? Was it issued *the right way*?

Comment: _"I have overstayed in Turkey for 8 months now"_ Why?

Answer (score 10):

You can go straight to Canada from Turkey.

Note though that the Turkish authorities at exit can harass you at exit, however more importantly the immigration officer at your entry point into Canada can refuse you entry if upon your landing interview he finds you are not trustworthy because you overstayed in Turkey for such a long time without good reason and hence [inadmissible](http://www.cic.gc.ca/EnGLIsh/information/inadmissibility/who.asp) for that or other reasons typically related to fraud. Basically you are an illegal immigrant in Turkey thus you have a poor immigration history. A competent immigration officer at the airport will refuse you entry barring some strong extenuating evidence.

You are particularly at risk because Canadian visas show where the visa was issued. If it indicates it was issued in your home country or somewhere outside Turkey, the immigration officer will be inclined to *dig for more information* like was the visa properly issued. It would be **best** if you went back to your home country and then on to Canada a little later. In that case the likelihood of questions about your illegal stay in Turkey during your entry point into Canada would be much lower.

Comment: What happens if the OP is refused entry when coming directly from Turkey? Will they be deported *back to Turkey*?

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga No. International rules say you get deported to a location where you are _admissible_.

Comment: Hmm.  If there is a risk Canadian immigration may not admit, isn't there a high risk that the airline won't let him board in Turkey (because otherwise they will be on the hook to fly him to wherever)?

Comment: In my experience airline officials typically only care about having a valid visa. Border agents however are the ones who dig deeper.

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga most likely refused entry, and the airline is then obliged to take him back where he came from i.e. Turkey.  Where he will most likely be refused entry too, but without any further help from the airline so a new ticket to his homeland from there.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen which is it? Sheik Paul is saying *no*, not Turkey, but you are saying *yes*, Turkey.